# Error constructing TableReader: rspecifier is scp:data/train/split1/1/feats.scp

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, kaldi

I followed the kaldi for dummies tutorial but I encounter this error on the MONO TRAINING part:
===== MONO TRAINING =====

steps/train_mono.sh --nj 1 --cmd run.pl data/train data/lang exp/mono
steps/train_mono.sh: Initializing monophone system.
feat-to-dim 'ark,s,cs:apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/train/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/train/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/train/split1/1/feats.scp ark:- | add-deltas ark:- ark:- |' -
apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/train/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/train/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/train/split1/1/feats.scp ark:-
add-deltas ark:- ark:-

**WARNING (apply-cmvn[5.5.863~1-813b7]:Open():util/kaldi-table-inl.h:106) Failed to open script file data/train/split1/1/feats.scp**

**ERROR (apply-cmvn[5.5.863~1-813b7]:SequentialTableReader():util/kaldi-table-inl.h:860) Error constructing TableReader: rspecifier is scp:data/train/split1/1/feats.scp**

[ Stack-Trace: ]
/home/jasonbourne/kaldi/src/lib/libkaldi-base.so(kaldi::MessageLogger::LogMessage() const+0xb42) [0x7f046fa3c692]
apply-cmvn(kaldi::MessageLogger::LogAndThrow::operator=(kaldi::MessageLogger const&)+0x21) [0x55f1724e2f3f]
apply-cmvn(kaldi::SequentialTableReaderkaldi::KaldiObjectHolder<kaldi::Matrix<float > >::SequentialTableReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)+0xc2) [0x55f1724ea550]
apply-cmvn(main+0x79b) [0x55f1724e0995]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f046eea6bf7]
apply-cmvn(_start+0x2a) [0x55f1724e011a]

kaldi::KaldiFatalErrorERROR (feat-to-dim[5.5.863~1-813b7]:main():feat-to-dim.cc:58) Could not read any features (empty archive?)

I tried deleting the autogenerated split folder in digits/data/train/ folder, then run again but still the same issue

I shouldn't have any utf8 issues since I'm just trying audio that says 1, 2, 3 and the corresponding text is also one, two, three

I also found a youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEMVk7r8_-M) tutorial and the assumption is after cloning his code (https://github.com/Muradean/kaldi_toy_example) then executing run, it should be working already but I get the same error: Error constructing TableReader: rspecifier is scp:data/train/split1/1/feats.scp

Sorry, I'm a newbie. I hope you could guide me.

Comment: For anyone else who sees this, the error is because `data/train/split1/1/feats.scp` does not exist. I'm guessing OP did not run the feature extraction step

Answer (score 1):

@Nimitz14, you're right, feature extraction wasn't successful.

I've had this issue when my `wav.scp` files were corrupted, so Kaldi couldn't fine audio files to extract features.
They should look like this:
`<fileID> /path/to/file/<fileID>.wav`

For me, the path to the file wasn't correct.

Hope, that helps.